# Why is my message not sending textarea?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an online code editor and when your done I want to give the user an option of sending all the code to himself in an email but whenever I try to the website doesn't send the code in the `<textarea></textarea>` tags. This is my code. Tell me if you need the JavaScript and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta name = "author" content = "Adam S. Oates">
        <meta name = "description" content = "This HTML file was created to test new thigns I learn">
        <meta name = "title" content = "Online Code Editor">
        <title title = "Online Code Editor">
            Online Code Editor
        </title>
        <link rel = "apple-touch-icon" href = "">
        <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            Gigaboy <span id = "code"></span> Editor
        </header>

        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "post">
            <textarea autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "Type HTML Here" id = "HTMLeditor" name = "HTMLeditor"></textarea>
            <a id="CSS"></a>
            <textarea autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "Type CSS Here" id = "CSSeditor" name = "CSSeditor"></textarea>
            <a id="JavaScript"></a>
            <textarea autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "Type JavaScript Here" id = "JSeditor" name = "JSeditor"></textarea>
            <span id = "see-result">View Result</span>
            <select id = "jqueryMode">
                <option value = "OFF">Disable JQuery</option>
                <option value = "ON">Enable JQuery</option>
            </select>
            <select id = "bootstrapMode">
                <option value = "OFF">Disable Bootstrap</option>
                <option value = "ON">Enable Bootstrap</option>
            </select>
            <select id = "gigaboyMode">
                <option value = "OFF">Disable GigaboyStyle.js</option>
                <option value = "ON">Enable GigaboyStyle.js</option>
            </select>
            <span id = "emailCode">
                    <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Send Code to You Email">
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
            </span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?PHP

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $msg = str_replace("\n", "<br>", str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $_POST['HTMLeditor']));
        $msg = str_replace("\n", "<br>", str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $_POST['CSSeditor']));
        $msg = str_replace("\n", "<br>", str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $_POST['JSeditor']));

        $HTML = htmlspecialchars($_POST['HTMLeditor']);
        $CSS = htmlspecialchars($_POST['CSSeditor']);
        $JS = htmlspecialchars($_POST['JSeditor']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Code Made at Gigaboy Code Editor Online";
        $message = "HTML5 Code: <br><br>" . $HTML . "<br><br><br>CSS Code: <br><br>" . $CSS . "<br><br><br>JavaScript Code: <br><br>" . $JS;

        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing Javascript - a client side code, with PHP - a server side code. They only ever "communicate" through AJAX.

Comment: The PHP code runs when the page is generated on the server, LONG before any of the html ever reaches the client. therefore the form hasn't been presented to the user, and it's impossible for them to fill it in, because it never reaches them until AFTER php has completed.

Comment: I tested your newly-edited code in your question; there's nothing wrong with it. You also have some other `<select>`'s with only id's and JS stuff that we have no idea what they're supposed to do. Make sure you did reload that page of yours and that caching isn't an issue here.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything and check your JS console. Plus, your headers don't contain a `From:` which mail expects to be an email address.

Comment: *"I want to give the user an option of sending all the code to himself in an email"* - That really isn't a good idea. Anyone could enter anybody's email address in there and SPAM the heck out of your server, in turn most likely putting your site on a blacklist. You had better rethink this. Once you're blacklisted, it's much harder to get unlisted.

Answer (score 3):

All form elements (including text areas) need to be placed between your opening and closing form tags.

Comment: I tried that but now it gives me the 403 Forbidden Error whenever I click send.

Comment: You will also want to remove this text: `onclick = "<?PHP sendCode(); ?>"` and remove the opening and closing function lines: `function sendCode() {` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of significant things wrong here...

---

First, your form elements (`input`, `select`, etc.) aren't actually *in a form*.  They need to be between these tags:

```
<form method = "post">
    <!-- form elements go in here -->
</form>
```

Otherwise that `form` is only going to post what it knows about, which is currently just an `input type="email"` and an `input type="submit"`, nothing more.

---

Second, this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
<input type = "submit" onclick = "<?PHP sendCode(); ?>" value = "Send">
```

This will execute `sendCode()` *before your page even loads*.  And, since there are no form values at that time, that function won't do anything.  Then this will simply produce this markup:

```
<input type = "submit" onclick = "" value = "Send">
```

So you're basically telling the submit button not to do anything (unsuccessfully, though).  Then when you *do* submit the form, that will *coincidentally* execute that function again, but not when you think it does.

The best recommendation I can give in this case is really to walk through some PHP tutorials from the beginning.  PHP runs *on the server* before the page is even sent to the client.  Then the client-side code runs *in the browser* long after the PHP is done.  They don't mix.

To fix what you have in this case though, essentially you can remove that `onclick` entirely:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Send">
```

and remove the function notation entirely:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // your code here
}

?>
```

There's no need for a function here, given the structure of what you're doing.  This code is going to execute every time the page is requested, before sending the page to the browser.  If the request doesn't include any POST data, then that's exactly what this `if` statement already checks.

Comment: This `<input type = "submit" onclick = "<?PHP sendCode(); ?>">` does work I use it on 2 other websites and it works fine.

Comment: @DorkFace: By coincidence alone.  It's not doing what you think it does.  I suggest you learn what the code is *actually* doing rather than assuming it's right, it will help you solve problems (like this one) when the code doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: There's is 2 ways you can get if a form is submitted I always use the one above and the other way is this `if ($_POST['sendCode']) {Type code here}`

Comment: @DorkFace: Yes, that part is correct.  But wrapping it in a function in this case in unnecessary.  And calling that function where you're calling it is downright misleading and will lead to confusion.

Comment: @DorkFace David is correct here. You cannot call a PHP function from within the browser. If it has worked before it has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: @David I edited the question and changed the code is this what you think it should be?